# Single Page App won't show up in iframe on a asp.net web app

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I am trying to get a Single Page application to show up in an `iframe` on a separate asp.net web application.

I can get just about anything else to show up in that `iframe` except single page apps. This is all for testing purposes for a current web application being used so I have to do it this way.

This is the html:

```
<iframe name="frameMain" width="800" height="450" src="http://localhost:51219 ">
</iframe>
```

When I debug it I get a 403 forbidden error.

Comment: Check app for x-frame-options header which would prevent it from being rendered in an iFrame.

Comment: I don't see a x-frame-options header in the web.config. I tried setting up the x-frame options to allow from my web application. still the same error.

Comment: Do you have a default page defined?  Perhaps it's trying to enumerate the root directory.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You need to specify the SPA's startup page in the src. I am still not sure as to why it wouldn't just go right to the startup page to begin with.